# How to get gaze/cursor coordinates in Hololens?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens

I'm trying to get the gaze coordinates from the Hololens. The main idea is get the intersection between my look ray and the Hololens mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you would need to do is get a reference to the Cursor Game Object and then get its position. That will get you the coordinates for where you are looking at.

`public GameObject Cursor;`

`Vector3 gazePos = Cursor.transform.position;`

Comment: This is incorrect as the Hololens does not *have* a Cursor. The notion of `Gaze` takes the place of it, but the user's gaze can't actually move around on the screen: its affixed to the center of the visible rendered area and the user turns their head to look in different directions (and that's what moves the gaze: the camera rotates inside the virtual scene).

Comment: I guess I should have clarified if he is using the Cursor from the HoloToolKit. I just assumed this was this case since in the question he references the cursor.

Comment: i'm using Hololens cursor. Thank you so much, that´s resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your scene should have a mainCamera object which represents the position of the headset, getting the transform on this object should give you what you are looking for. The snippet below should do it for you.

```
Camera.mainCamera.gameObject.transform.position
```

You can check the Unity documentation for cameras here :

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html

Also check out GazeManager from the Mixed reality toolkit.

https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Input/Scripts/Gaze/GazeManager.cs

Comment: Thank you so much! This code give me the position of the hololens which is not exactly that i want but it was so helpful.